# Rails: Get placement of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, object

Say I've got a `Questions` and `Answer` model and I pull all the answers to a specific question.

I can easily do an `each_with_index` to and figure out what the index or "placement" of an answer is (in relation to the other answers to that specific question).

But, say I want to get a specific answer...how could I still figure out what the index of that answer is in relation to all the other answers associated with a specific question.

Example `Answer` data:

```
ID  text      question_id
23  awesome   3
27  boooyah   3
38  snap      3
```

If I did `Answer.find(27)` how can I figure out that record is the second item (assuming I'm ordering by ID...though I could order by any field).

Comment: is position is really important to you then just add a position column in your table.

Comment: But it needs to be dynamic. Like if I do an `ORDER BY created_at` then that changes the position. I'm not wanting to keep them in a certain order, I'm wanting to find out where in a specific ordering they are.

Comment: not unless you saved the position in the database like i suggested. if you saved the position, boooyah will always have position 2, no matter what your query was

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question

  def position(column = 'id', order = 'ASC')
    order_by = "#{column} #{order}"
    arrow = order.capitalize == "ASC" ? "<=" : ">="
    question.answers.where("#{column} #{arrow} (?)", self.send(column)).order(order_by).count
  end    
end

Answer.find(27).position
Answer.find(27).position("updated_at")
Answer.find(27).position("updated_at", "DESC")
```

Comment: This would only work for sorting by `id`. Ordering by something else would have the same effect since you are applying the `where('id <= ?', self.id)` condition always and then getting the count.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, it's not tested but you can see the concept.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :question

  def placement(ordering_by => 'id ASC')
    question.answers.order(ordering_by).index(self)
  end

end
```